# Netbeans integration with Mac OS X native PHP, PEAR PHPUnit config

Tags: php, netbeans, development-environment, phpunit, pear

I am trying to integrate Netbeans 6.9 or 7 into my development environment (Mac OS X 10.6.7 native PHP no stacks) but no matter what I try I am not getting Netbeans to recognize my PHP interpreter (/usr/bin/php) or my PHPUnit script (/usr/local/bin/phpunit).

Anybody got some less than obvious ideas, although I may have missed one of those.  I have exhausted search terms on the web trying to find someone who went through the same problems but nothing has come of it.

**EDIT**
Well for the past day I have been using `phpunit --version` to verify my phpunit version (3.5.13) and `pear list` to verify my PEAR 1.9.2 install.  Well I just discovered the `pear list-all` which shows phpunit as 1.3.2.  Upon entering `pear upgrade phpunit/PHPUnit` the response I get is `Nothing to upgrade`

This may explain the PHPUnit script problem since apparently there are 2 versions of PHPUnit installed and the one I am trying to point to must not be tied into PEAR.

```
which php /usr/bin/php
which pear /usr/local/bin/pear
which phpunit /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: what means "not getting netbeans to recognize"? What do you expect? What do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally gave up on netbeans and went over to PhpStorm 2.  I am not having any problems there and it does what I need.  cweiske I apprecaite the info provided as that was of great help for things I did not realize.

Comment: "I gave up" is not an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

## Wrong phpunit versions

```
$ pear list-all
```

shows the packages from the default channel, which is "pear.php.net" unless you configured it otherwise. You did install phpunit from pear.phpunit.de, which is a different channel.
PHPUnit previously (version 1) was hosted on pear.php.net but moved to its own channel.
Running

```
$ pear list-all -c pear.phpunit.de
```

shows `phpunit 3.5.13`.

```
$ pear install phpunit/phpunit
```

is actually the same as

```
$ pear install pear.phpunit.de/phpunit
```

because `phpunit` is the short name/alias for the `pear.phpunit.de` channel.

## Two phpunits installed

You probably do not have two phpunit versions installed. "list-all" lists *all* available packages on a channel, not only local/installed ones.

Comment: I apprecaite the info provided as that was of great help for things I did not realize.